# How can you skip an "after_initialize" method if updating a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an after_initialize method that I only want to call if I'm not updating a record. For example, something like the following:

```
after_initialize :set_some_name, :unless => :updating?
```

For example, `Task.find(123).title` should call the `after_initialize` method. `Task.find(123).save!(:title => "something")` should *not* call the `after_initialize` method.

Of course the "updating?" method doesn't exist in Rails. Is there an equivalent method or a way to do so?

Comment: after_initialize is called before you save the record, so what do you mean?

Comment: after_initialize is also called when you find a record - for example, Task.find(123). Is there away to only use it for finding a record and not before saving a record?

Comment: true, its called also when retrieving a record, but not before saving a record, so i still don't understand what you need. If you mean that you want `set_some_name` to be triggered only on a persisted record, you can use the method `.new_record?`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails after\_initialize only on "new"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610277/rails-after-initialize-only-on-new)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion :) For example, if the record already exists, and you update it, after_initialize will be called (which I don't want). To be clearer, I'm trying to do something like: "after_initialize :set_some_name, :unless => :updating?"

Comment: You can place all your needed staff into constructor method, don't you? It is called only for records not being found in db, but created via `.new()`.

Comment: so I think you'd want to use the `new_record?` method: 

`after_initialize :set_some_name, if: lambda { self.new_record? }`

Comment: Yossi, thanks for trying to help :) I particularly want to use the after_initialize for existing records too (except when I'm updating the record). For example, Task.find(123).title should call the after_initialize method. Task.find(123).save!(:title => "something") should *not* call the after_initialize method. Is there a way to do that in Rails?

Comment: Thanks Arantir :) Do you know have an example of a constructor method to do so? I googled but have no idea where to start.

Comment: @sjsc, `initialize` method is a constructor in Ruby. And, as I know, Rails doesn't call it (in case of ActiveRecord) when retrieving records from db. Default `initialize` takes a hash of model fields to be assigned, so you may want to call `super` to execute parent's constructor method as well before your code.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to call the callback on save?

Comment: @sjsc, after your edit I'm finally confused. Rails doesn't know what you want to do further at the moment you're calling `find()`. It looks like you want to override attributes attributes accessors to do what you want when you read some field's value.

Comment: @Bulezim, I want to set a record's value without saving it (since I want to keep pre-existing values). The value is set based on a condition (for example, setting a record's price based on today's selling price, without overwriting the original price in db)

Comment: @sjsc, if you want to get, for example, `price` with some special conditions you can just override it's getter (simply define `price` method and return modified price). Rails doesn't call those methods while persisting records to db.

Comment: @sjsc If I understood you only need to override the attribute reader.

Comment: Awesome! That's a far better solution than how I solved it :) Thank you Arantir and Belezim!!

Answer (score 8):

I think you are looking for this method :

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new_record%3F

In your after_initialize function, you can then check if the record has already been saved before doing your treatment.

Maybe

```
after_initialize :set_some_name, if: :new_record?
```

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I meant "saving" should take into account "updating" as well. I updated the question to make it clearer, meaning that after_initialize should not be called if I'm updating a record.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like so :)

```
after_initialize :set_alternative_title, :unless => :name_is_alternative_title?

def set_alternative_title
  self.title = "Alternative title"
end

def name_is_alternative_title?
  self.title == "Alternative title"
end
```